# Unable to get into ubuntu-recovery mode

Tags: boot, 10.10, recovery-mode, grub-legacy

I am working on a 7 year old laptop with Ubuntu 10.10, i.e Maverick. It's 32-bit. While the ubuntu boots up with some issues, particularly with the error of the BIOS clock, whose battery has died some time ago. While I press 'I' to ignore the error, bootup normally and go use ubuntu normally, I am unable to get into recovery mode as I need to change the sudo password.

Whenever I try to go into recovery mode it doesn't even load the menu options, all it does is loop endlessly something like this line: " Loading disk fsck: ... done" (not precisely this line but something like that) .

Also this is ubuntu was modified by some company for their own purposes, so I'm pretty sure they must have tried to disable the ubuntu recovery mode option. I just need help to confirm that.

I've tried to use boot-repair to fix Grub, but it didn't work and I still can't get into recovery mode.

Lemme know If there's any more detail I can add for understanding this issue.

[Here's the boot-repair report file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24181215/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot Ubuntu live from a a flash drive and choose **try Ubuntu without installing**. Once inside open up a terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l` and find where Linux is installed (/dev/sda*) - * *could be any number*

Next create a directory in your media folder corresponding to where Linux is installed whether it's sda1,sda2,sda3....etc. by running the following command

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda*
```

(* being the number for the partition)

Then mount the hard drive to that folder by running:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda* /media/sda*
```

(*again keep in mind the asterisk indicates where Linux is installed*)

Once mounted run `sudo chroot /media/sda*`

Then finally `passwd geek`

You should be able to change your password now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that you can change ubuntu password without going to the terminal window from ubuntu recovery mode.